# Using battery bank as a continuous battery backup / supply for USB devices

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi, usb-c, usb-hub

I have a Raspberry Pi and mega-4 powered USB hub working well, with one USB-C power input each.

The battery bank has 2 USB ports, one for each device.

The charger (bottom left) is a standard buck charger that converts 7 to 22 V DC input to USB charging output.

The charger will get input from a create 3 irobot when docked, and when not docked will have it's power removed.

This has been tested and works fine, but when docked it will be both charging the battery and providing the 2 devices with power.

Do I need a DC power switch on the output of each battery and separate DC supply when the battery is charging? Are there electrical or health and safety issues?

[image: Battery Bank Raspberry Pi Supply]

[image]

Comment: Please draw a block diagram of what you have and how it’s connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need a DC power switch on the output of each battery and separate DC supply when the battery is charging?

No. What you have will work fine as is.

> Are there electrical issues?

No.

> Are there health and safety issues?

Don't ingest any of those components. Don't step on them barefoot.

Comment: I always fail at the "don't ingest the components" hurdle!  Thanks, now going to work on an RPi relay to turn off the create3 battery power input when not in the dock.

Comment: Very annoying!  This works fine with power in, but when I switch to battery backup mode the battery looses power and shuts down the Raspberry Pi and components before powering them back on.